# Update v-model from state from store

Tags: ionic-framework, vuejs3, vuex, pinia

I have an input field component that i am trying to reset whenever the field loses focus or whenever the user presses the Escape button.
However the v-model that comes from a store state is never updated, why is that?
Also is this the correct way to deal with input components?

Input child component:

```
<template>
 <ion-input
  placeholder="Name"
  :modelValue="modelValue"
  @ionInput="editedName= $event.target.value;"
  @ion-focus="currentName = modelValue"
  @keydown.esc="$emit('update:modelValue', currentName )"
  @ion-blur="$emit('update:modelValue', currentName )"
/>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import {IonInput} from "@ionic/vue";
import { onBeforeMount, ref } from "vue";
  
interface Props {
  id: string;
  modelValue: string;
}
const props = defineProps<Props>();

const currentName = ref();
const editedName= ref();
const edit = ref(false)
</script>
```

And this is how how i use it on my parent component:

```
<template>
 <ItemField
  :id="data.id"
  v-model="data.name"
 />
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import ItemField from '@/components/admin/ItemField.vue'
import {myStore} from '@/stores/myStore'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
import { spaceType } from "@/types";

const store = myStore()
const { data} = storeToRefs(store );
</script>
```

What exactly am i doing wrong?

Comment: I had similar issue but it was solved. Would it be okay with you if I post an answer but I am using tailwind and nuxt 3 for it so I don't have to import things around files. The main focus is to solve the reset issue when the field is not focused or the user pressed the `esc` key. Let me know

Comment: sure thing, you can post anything as long as you think it is relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `:modelValue` isn't a property according to the [ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input#value), it should be `:value`

```html
<ion-input
  :value="modelValue"
/>
```

Second, change your `@input` event to update the modelValue which will update the store data.name value.  The emits from `@keydown.esc` and `@blur` should do their job of resetting data.name to the previous value

```js
<template>
  <ion-input
    placeholder="Name"
    :value="modelValue"
    @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
    @focus="currentName = modelValue"
    @keydown.esc="$emit('update:modelValue', currentName)"
    @blur="$emit('update:modelValue', currentName)"
  />
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import { IonInput } from "@ionic/vue";
import { ref } from 'vue'

interface Props {
  id: string
  modelValue: string
}
defineProps<Props>()
defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])

const currentName = ref('')
</script>
```

Comment: editedName and currentName  are the edited value of the input and currentName is the value the input field starts with

Comment: also no, the keydown and blur methods should reset the input value to it's original value.
if the model input was 'car' and i change it 'bike', if i press esc it should reset it back to 'car'. But that is not happening.

Comment: I see now.  Well, if the @input is changed to update the actual store value instead of `editedName` it should actually start doing what you want.  I've updated my answer to include the minimal code needed to achieve.